# How important is learning Algorithms for high level language programmers

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How important is studying algorithms and theory is to becoming a great programmer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53123/how-important-is-studying-algorithms-and-theory-is-to-becoming-a-great-programme)

Today I learned the fast sort Algorithm. I doubt I will ever implement my own version though as C# has its own built in Sort method for lists and arrays.

How important is learning Algorithms for high level language programmers? In my example I gained no benifit from knowing the Algorithm but perhaps my example was too trivial to be accurate?

Comment: Do you expect that the vendor will always provide everything you will ever need?

Comment: How important is doing something interesting/challenging in your career? Also, did you learn when NOT to use the built in sort? Quicksort is terrible when the data is almost sorted already which is why it is important to know other sorts/algorithms...

Comment: Ironically, that is almost the exact reverse of [Is it reasonable to expect knowing the whole stack bottom up?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122648/is-it-reasonable-to-expect-knowing-the-whole-stack-bottom-up)

Comment: @Péter, I think the focus on high-level programming could make this enough of a distinction from your duplicate, if the answers would focus more on that aspect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which sort algorithm did you learn?  Quicksort, heapsort, bucket sort, insertion sort, radix sort, bubble sort, or [a bunch of possible others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)?  Which sorting algorithm does C# use?

What I'm getting at is that there are many possible strategies for many algorithms and data structures (containers are another good example) that each have their own benefits and drawbacks.  Any single "generic" implementation will have made a specific choice regarding those benefits and drawbacks - and that choice may not be optimal for your *particular* problem.

Now, that may not be an issue, as you don't want to prematurely optimize anyway, but being *unaware* of these choices, drawbacks and benefits leaves you a gaping blind spot in your well-roundedness as a developer.

Answer (score 29):

You know you will not always write trivial code, at some point in your projects you will have to write an algorithm that solves a hard problem for example matching objects with each other according to some data. And when you do that, you will have in mind the complexity of an algorithm so the solution you come up with will have a perspective of an algorithm designer in it.

Comment: +1 `you will have in mind the complexity of an algorithm so the solution you come up with will have a perspective of an algorithm designer in it` Brilliant. _Learning algorithms_ is learning the [algorithmic process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_solving) and perspective, not so much the algorithms themselves.

Comment: In that case I would just use another C# feature like lambda functions

Comment: @TomSquires - language features are completely orthogonal to algorithms.  If you know an algorithm you can usually implement it in any turing-complete programming language.  In other words that knowledge applies to programming in the general, not specific to one language or implementation.  Now, lambdas are actually a generic mathematical concept themselves, not just a language feature, but that's another can of worms :).

Comment: @TomSquires -- I'm not sure if you're joking or not.

Comment: @TomSquires - also you're assuming you're working in .NET.  Technologies change.  Jobs change.

Answer (score 6):

> I doubt I will ever implement my own version though as C# has its own built in Sort method for lists and arrays.

Let's say you need a fast median algorithm. Few standard libraries I'm aware of have such a thing built-in. But if you know how quicksort works, it's very simple to modify it to get an algorithm for finding the median in O(n) time. My point is: Algorithms&data structures often have to be modified for a specific problem, and to be able to do that, you need to know and understand them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not be misled by the fact that you want to program in a high-level language. A high-level language gives you lots of abstractions (data types, control structures, memory management, standard libraries, etc) that make certain tasks easier for you.

As a result, a task that once seemed very complex (e.g. sending an email through smtp) can now be achieved by performing a few calls to some library functions. What is the consequence of this? That it is possible to construct applications that are much more complex than before.

So, at the end of the day you will still have to do with very complex software projects because high level languages have only taken the complexity of software to a different level. What I mean is that, say, implementing a business application in C#, Java or Scala can be as complex as (or even more complex than) implementing a device driver in C / assembly.

So, IMO, high-level programming languages will not protect you from having to deal with real algorithmic or architectural problems: they have made **specific programming tasks** easier, but they haven't made programming less difficult or challenging in general.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would not use a C# built in Sort method (or anything else for that matter) without knowing what it does and how it goes about doing it, in all its detail -- that is just not being a programmer. You could be an excellent coding help to a programmer, though.

Comment: I disagree: you can and _will_ use lots of built-in functions without necessarily understanding their inner workings; just knowing their contracts and high level properties is enough. However, that *does not mean* that you shouldn't know any algorithms as a general principle, because it's very likely there will be situations where you need to understand, tweak or compare algorithms. Or, god forbid, provide your own implementations!

Comment: This is a [no true scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) argument.  *Why* is it "just not being a programmer"?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Let me first checkout "no true scotsman" :)

Comment: Oh yes, but this is certainly not an argument without substance.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm knowledge is absolutely essential for programmers for the following reasons:

1. Programming is everything about handling large amounts of details. Details that are all linked together to a consistent system. Algorithms are just well known patterns of details, where solutions are known. 99% of the cases the details are not structured like those well known patterns expect, and the algorithms need to be customised to the particular situation -- it's just not possible to write any significant software without algorithm knowledge.
2. Data structures are another aspect of the same problem. Computer memory storage lets us store information. But deciding correct representation in the computer memory for that information in every state during the algorithm execution is significant problem in itself. If there are problems with learning algorithms, then learning data structures is simpler way to learn the same thing.
3. In the end, it's all about bits in the computer memory. It's either 0 or 1. There are sequences of bits like 010, and then those are then boxed inside data types. During the lifetime of the data, the value of the bits will change, and the system moves from one state to another repeatedly, and finally a normal form - the result of the program is reached, and execution stops until it is again activated by an external event.
4. These execution sequences in the program from activation of the execution to the normal form can become very complex. Handling this complexity together with data changes is what algorithms are all about.

Answer (score 1):

Learning algorithms (and, last but not least, data structures) is most important. Even if you should of course use the sort function of your language's library, you then know that sorting is comparatively not a cheap operation, hence you will write your code so that sorting is done in the right moment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to know much about how a car functions to drive it but you'll almost certainly, at best, only be a relatively average driver. The more you know about cars the better driver you can be. To be an elite driver, you will know as much as possible about every detail of your car, its engine, even your physiology and the ergo-dynamics of the cockpit. It then doesn't much matter what car you drive, you'll be able to quickly assess its capabilities and drive it effectively.

Or, simply, as with anything, the more you know, the better at that profession you will be.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the analogy seems flawed: Wouldn't the car driver be computer program user? Could you be a good "vehicle developer" without knowing how a car's components work?

Comment: -1 `Proof by analogy is fraud.` Stroustrup, Bjarne. The C++ Programming Language. pp. 692.

Comment: @nikie Reread by replacing "driver" with "programmer" and replacing "car" with "algorithm" or "program".

Comment: @YannisRizos where is my analogy considered a proof? It's simply an example of my belief about the study of algorithms. You don't have to agree but it isn't a proof of anything so it isn't a logical fallacy.

Comment: @nicerobot You are trying to prove a point, though... `Or, simply, as with anything, the more you know, the better at that profession you will be.` That's your point and the only thing you provided to back it up (~prove) is an analogy. A flawed one, imho, for the same reasons highlighted by nikie  - but that's another matter, I'd downvote a good analogy too.

Comment: @YannisRizos Incorrect. It is in no way an attempt to prove anything. It's simply an analogy of my belief about learning and programming. If i wanted to prove my belief, i would have to provide something that is even provable and then demonstrate the truth of my argument. What i provided is simply a statement of my beliefs using an analogy and a great analogy at that.

Comment: @nicerobot `...have to provide something that is even provable and then demonstrate the truth of my argument` If that wasn't your motivation, you shouldn't answered. This isn't a discussion board and the question didn't ask for general opinions on learning and programming.

Comment: @YannisRizos o_O Huh? "How important is learning Algorithms for high level language programmers" By it's very nature, that question is subjective which implies it can't be proven and that all "answers" will be the authors' opinion and hence, essentially a discussion board. Wow! You just want to disagree with me. That's fine! Have fun with that.

Comment: @nicerobot: replacing car with algorithm and driver with programmer: "*You don't have to know much about how an algorithm functions to program it...*". Definitely not true.

Comment: @nikie Can you use sort without knowing how sort works internally? Which sorting algorithm it uses? Of course you can! And that was Tom's question!

Comment: @nicerobot There are several guidelines on answers on subjective questions on the [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Some of them are: `inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”`, `invite sharing experiences over opinions.` and `insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references`. These guidelines are in place to prevent turning subjective questions into open ended discussions. The other answers follow the guidelines, more or less. Your's doesn't.

Comment: @YannisRizos Again, you just want to disagree with me. Fine! A good analogy is, at the same time, both a sharing experience and imparts how and why through well understood comparisons.

Comment: @nicerobot I'm really sorry to have to say it again, but it is not a good analogy. Consider the fact that your answer is supposed to be helpful, but still there are two people out there that tell you again and again that your analogy is flawed (it doesn't really make sense). You can argue for hours that it's a good one, and I can argue for hours that it's a bad one. But you are the one providing the answer, you are supposed to want to help me (the reader) get your message. I don't get it. I get all the other answers but not yours. It's nothing personal, I'm commenting on the answer, not you.

Comment: The point of providing an answer is not to show how clever you are (which I'm sure you are), but help others by conveying a message. An analogy is open to interpretations, hence it's a terrible way to convey a message. Some people are bound to interpret it differently that what you actually mean. A bad analogy is even worse. I may be dumb for not getting it at first, but your motivation should be to help everyone, not just those that "get it".

Comment: @YannisRizos http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy is "the core of cognition" Mine is hardly clever. It's obvious and accurate and can apply to anyone that understands what a car and a driver are and so even people who don't understand what programming and algorithms are can grasp how programmers relate to drivers. Anyone who doesn't get such a simple analogy, i believe, is intentionally looking for ways to misunderstand it. I'm done arguing this. It's the pickiness and bullheadedness of people like you that make me not post more to stack sites. I've read your kind of comments far too often.

Answer (score 1):

Every program *is* an algorithm. Learning algorithms is about learning the more generic patterns, and the concepts involved. I never need a sort algorithm by itself, but I need a sort plus a tree plus a unique set of steps to solve a problem. I end up with an algorithm that is unique to this problem.

If I don't know about designing algorithms, how will I solve my problem? You probably won't write a new sort, but the classic quote "Data structures + algorithms = program" is true for every program. You have to know which algorithm to use where, and how to build your own.

I leave aside completely the fact that algorithms are useless in a data vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of questions on Programmers.SE of the form "Do I need to know X to be a successful programmer?". Programming is a huge arena with thousands of different kinds of jobs, so no matter what 'X' is, the answer is 'No', because you can find some subset of programming jobs that doesn't need 'X'.

Unfortunately, what usually goes unsaid is that each time you decide to 'just get by' and blowing off some subject, you are  implicitly making choices about the sorts of programming jobs you are going to take in the future. None of us can know everything, so these choices have to be made, but they should be made with some thought for the future of your career, not just to avoid some current inconvenience or effort.

Yes, there are lots of programming jobs where a formal knowledge of algorithms would go to waste. The question is: Are those the sorts of jobs you want to be working at ten years from now? If not, you should now begin laying the groundwork to qualify for other jobs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in language features and library functions, like the sort function are  abstractions.  And when one of those abstractions [leaks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html), as they invariably do, you will not know what hit you, if you don't understand complexity of algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

I do not think that for a high level language programmer learning algorithms is important for being productive. It is like knowledge about how the compiler works, how the garbage collector works, how a finite state machine works, why floating point operations can lead to wrong calculation results, how ASCII is different from UTF-8 and so on and so on.

High level languages, which deliberately hide such low level stuff from the programmer, want to give you the possibility to concentrate on business rules. I have seen many programmers lacking of "low level" knowledge and still get their work right.

Like a mechanic can get the most out of his car than an ordinary car driver, a programmer with (at least some) "low level" knowledge will make better decisions. For sorting algorithms this means for example: If you know that that the data is partly sorted then you will likely choose Bubble sort. The programmer guy next to you, who does not know this, might choose a slower algorithm. Will he get his work done: Yes. Will he be able to explain the stakeholders if he can make the sorting faster? Maybe not.

However: Does it matter? For most applications which are programmed with a high level programming language, it rarely matters. But in those rare cases, wrong decisions can have devastating consequences. The wrong sorting algorithm will make your program slow, the wrong decision over the character encoding will make in internationalization impossible, and the wrong number type lead to wrong calculation results.

So it is up to you: Do you want to be productive or do you also want to make the right decisions?